# captured images dont display to my tracks

Tags: android, android-intent

Why don't my tracks display the image from my custom camera? What is the algo of sending data or Uri to my tracks from my custom camera?

I'd use this code but no luck

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra("com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MYTRACKS", fileUri);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sent image to MyTracks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235401/how-to-sent-image-to-mytracks)

Comment: yes...it because nobody answered to my question. I thought my first question is rejected